# Ruby puts<<PARAGRAPH

Tags: ruby

```
puts <<PARAGRAPH
There's somthing going on here.
With the PARAGRAPH thing
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6 .
PARAGRAPH
```

This can work, using Notepad++

But why this can't work?

```
puts <<PARAGRAPH
aaaa Aa
aaa
AA
PARAGRAPH
```

> test.rb:1: syntax error,unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end

Thanks!

Comment: Both your snippets work for me.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that in your second snippet `PARAGRAPH` is not at the begging of the line.

The multi-line strings in ruby, are weird that way. The terminating character (whatever it may be) must be the first thing on a line to terminate the string, otherwise you will often see the syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure ensure that `PARAGRAPH` (the second instance) is a) spelled the same as your first instance, and b) at the start of the line, or change your code to:

```
def go
  puts <<-PARAGRAPH   # hyphen allows the end marker to be indented
    Hi mom!
  PARAGRAPH
end
```

For more information, read the [intro to Strings](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_stdtypes.html#strings) and the [full description](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#strings).

Answer (score 1):

The code works for me. One way I broke it was by adding space between << and PARAGRAPH

```
puts << PARAGRAPH
PARAGRAPH
```

This is different from the next example.

```
puts <<PARAGRAPH
PARAGRAPH
```

Edit: As I continue play with it I found that PARAGRAPH is just like any place holder. You can do the following and you will still get a paragraph in a string

```
puts <<ANYTHING_YOU_WANT
ANYTHING_YOU_WANT
```

I thought it was cool that it is not restricted only to the word PARAGRAPH. I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

I can get either version to error by adding additional spaces after the final `PARAGRAPH`.

Ensure that the closing `PARAGRAPH` is truly on a new line (per diedthreetimes' answer) and has no trailing characters (i.e. spaces, tabs, etc.)